# Django: how to transform an exception from a signal to a form error in CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-signals

For the need of checking uniqueness on an M2M field, I was advised to write a signal that is triggered when m2m changes. It works well.

However, when using a class based view to create a `Badge` object, I'd like to catch this exception and transform it into a form error, so that the error can be displayed in a clean way to the user, instead of getting a `HTTP 500` error.

I'm not sure how to do this in a clean way however. Usually it's easy because it's automatically handled with model `clean()` or form `clean()`, but not here.

#### signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Badge.restaurants.through)
def check_uniqueness(sender, **kwargs):
    badge = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    action = kwargs.get('action', None)
    restaurants = kwargs.get('pk_set', None)

    if action == 'pre_add':
        for restaurant_pk in restaurants:
            if Badge.objects.filter(identifier=badge.identifier).filter(restaurants=restaurant_pk):
                raise BadgeNotUnique(
                    f'Badge with identifier {badge.identifier} already exists '
                    f'for restaurant {Restaurant.objects.get(pk=restaurant_pk)}'
                )
```

#### views.py

```
class BadgesCreateView(PermissionRequiredCanHandleBadges, ModelInContextMixin, SubSectionBadges,
                       BillingClusterMixin,
                       CreateView):
    model = Badge
    template_name = "badges/badge_add.html"
    fields = ('identifier', 'owner', 'expiration', 'is_active', 'restaurants')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('bo:badge-list')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `form_valid` method of the view which is where the form (and therefore the instance and its relations) is saved:

```
class BadgesCreateView(..., CreateView):
    # ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            return super(BadgesCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        except BadgeNotUnique as e:
            form.add_error(
                'restaurants',  # None for non-field error
                e.args[0]
            )
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks a lot. I never thought it was possible to return `form_invalid()` from `form_valid()`!

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with that. But it does mean that you only get feedback on that particular error if there are no other errors. It would be cleaner to have a custom form (set) and detect this error in one of the `clean` methods, but then you can't just make easy use of your existing signal handler.

Comment: The only missing thing is the atomicity of transaction sothat a Badge object can not be created in case of error.